# Bug ao mostrar data de término de uma suspensão

Tags: bug, status-aceito, internacionalização

Estamos com um probleminha ao apresentar as datas de fim de suspensão de usuários penalizados.

[image: Erro ao apresentar a palavra em]

Eu conferi a *string* no Transifex e ela está assim

> Esta conta foi **$linkStart$** temporariamente suspensa **$linkEnd$** **$reason$**. O período de suspensão termina **$penaltyEndDate$**.

[image: string no transifex]

Ou seja, sabemos que o problema não é na tradução em si. Então deve ser algo no código.

Provavelmente é porque o código deve estar colocando a palavra "**em**" dentro da formatação da data e isto está fazendo com que a letra **m** seja tratada como **minuto**.

```
data.ToString("em dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Quando, na verdade, esta palavra deveria ser escapada

```
data.ToString("\"em\" dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

[Reprodução do erro e da solução no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5Gvr2)

---

## English Version

**Title:** Bug displaying suspension end date

We have a little problem displaying the suspension end dates for suspended users.

[image: Error displaying the word "em"]

I checked the string in Transifex, and it looks like this:

> Esta conta foi **$linkStart$** temporariamente suspensa **$linkEnd$** **$reason$**. O período de suspensão termina **$penaltyEndDate$**.

[image: string in Transifex]

Meaning we know the problem is not the translation itself. So it should be something in the code.

The code is probably putting the word "**em**" inside the date formatting, making the letter **m** be interpreted as **minute**.

```
data.ToString("em dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

When, in fact, the word should be escaped

```
data.ToString("\"em\" dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

[Error reproduction and solution in .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5Gvr2)